# Splitting date and time in Oracle SQl

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, split

I have a date time stored in the format mm/dd/yyyy HH24:mi:ss format(example 01/25/2005  10:10:15 PM). Is there any inbuilt function in Oracle SQL to obtain the date value and time value separately?

I cant use the space to split the 2 values because there are 2 spaces(One between date and time and the other between time and AM/PM)

Comment: An Oracle `date` has a day and time but it is not stored in a particular format.  Are you saying that you have a `date` column?  Or do you have a `varchar2` column where you are storing a string in a particular format?

Comment: Provide your table structure

Comment: Your second paragraph makes no sense. You **can** split a string at the **first** space no matter how many (other) spaces are in the string. Perhaps you meant to say "I don't know how to...", rather than "I can't"?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `date`, and you want to display the date and time portions separately, use `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(mydate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') datepart, to_char(mydate, 'hh24:mi:ss') timepart
from mytable
```

You control the format of the string representations with the second argument to `to_char()`.

If you have a string, and you want to split it into two after the first space, then use string functions:

```
select substr(mystr, 1, instr(mystr, ' ') - 1) datepart, substr(mystr, instr(mystr, ' ') + 1)
from mytable
```

Comment: Hi but I got an error when I executed this select to_char('1/22/2021  11:20:15 PM', 'mm/dd/yyy') , to_char('1/22/2021  11:20:15 PM', 'hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual

Comment: @KasunKumara: well, that is a string, not a date, so use the second solution given in the answer.

Comment: @KasunKumara, you may first convert your string to date format then apply to_char to extract date and time separately.  "select to_char(TO_DATE('1/22/2021 11:20:15 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'), 'mm/dd/yyyy') "DATE", to_char(TO_DATE('1/22/2021 11:20:15 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'), 'hh24:mi:ss') "TIME" FROM dual;"